# Multiple File Uploading using lightning input tag with type="file"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, fileupload

> I have found this code on internet and change it as per my need, but this code is not working if i increases the MAX_FILE_SIZE in helper

component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global" controller="Community_CreateVeterenRecord">

    <aura:attribute name="ShowModule" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="Id" />
    <!--Attributes for file-->
    <aura:attribute name="fileName" type="list" default="No File Selected." />
    <aura:attribute name="fileList" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accept" type="List" default="['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.pdf']"/>
    <!--Attributes for spinner-->
    <aura:attribute name="isSpinner" type="boolean" default="false"/>




 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ShowModule}">  


    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open acct-header--tier-modal slds-align_absolute-center">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!--Modal Header-->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                          size="large"
                                          variant="bare-inverse"
                                          onclick="{! c.HideMe }"
                                          alternativeText="Close" 
                                          class="slds-modal__close" />
                    
                    
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Record</h2>
                </header>  <!--/Modal Header-->
                
                <!--Modal Body-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
          


    <!--  New Reservation Form  -->
    <form class="slds-form--stacked" >               
                    
      
    <div class="fields-div">             
           <lightning:input type="text" class="alignField" label="Service Name" aura:id="serviceName"    required="true"/>
           <lightning:input type="text" class="alignField" label="Service Number" aura:id="serviceNumber"    required="true"/>
           <lightning:input type="text" class="alignField" label="Service Branch" aura:id="serviceBranch"    required="true"/>
           <lightning:input type="date" class="alignField" label="Service Start Date" aura:id="serviceStartDate" required="true"/>
           <lightning:input type="date" class="alignField" label="Service Stop Date" aura:id="serviceStopDate"  required="true"/>
       

        <!--Attachment-->
        <lightning:input aura:id="fileId" 
                onchange="{!c.handleFilesChange}"
                type="file" files="{!v.fileList}"
                accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg , application/pdf" 
                name="file" multiple="true"
                label="Upload Attachment"/>        
    
     
    <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error"> 
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.fileName}" var="fl">
       <div class="slds-text-body_small slds-text-color_error fName">{!fl}
           <a onclick="{!c.handleCancel}" data-recid="{!fl}">
               <span style="margin-left:2px;">
                   <lightning:icon class=" icn" iconName="action:close" size="xx-small" onclick="{! c.handleCancel }"/>
               </span>
           </a>    
       </div>
       </aura:iteration>
            </div> 
        <!--/Attachment-->
       
       <div class="slds-text-align_center">
           <lightning:button class="btn submit-button"  label="Submit" onclick="{!c.createVetRecord}"/>
       </div>
      <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" alternativeText="Processing.." title="Processing.." variant="brand" size="large" class="slds-hide"/>     

        </div>
            
        
    </form>
        <!--  /New Case Form -->
                    
                    
                </div> <!--/Modal Body-->
                
                        </div>
        </section>



<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </aura:if>    
    
    </aura:component>
```

> JsController

```
({
HideMe: function(component, event, helper)
{
      component.set("v.ShowModule", false);
   },
 

  ShowModuleBox: function(component, event, helper) 
    {
      component.set("v.ShowModule", true);
   },
    
    
    createVetRecord: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        debugger;
        //disable submitt button
    component.set("v.isSpinner", true); 
    //show spinner
    helper.showSpinner(component); 
    
    //get fields
    var serviceName = component.find("serviceName").get("v.value");
    var serviceNumber = component.find("serviceNumber").get("v.value");
    var serviceBranch = component.find("serviceBranch").get("v.value");
    var serviceStartDate = component.find("serviceStartDate").get("v.value"); 
    var serviceStopDate = component.find("serviceStopDate").get("v.value"); 
    
    //make server call
    var action = component.get("c.createVeterantRecord");
        //Set method parameters
        action.setParams({
            serviceName      : serviceName,
            serviceNumber    : serviceNumber,
            serviceBranch    : serviceBranch,
            serviceStartDate : serviceStartDate,
            serviceStopDate  : serviceStopDate
        
    });
    
                
        action.setCallback(this,function(response)
       {
            var state = response.getState();
            alert('state is '+ state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") 
            {
               alert('response record id is  '+response.getReturnValue());
               var result= response.getReturnValue();
               // set created record id as parent id for attachments
               component.set("v.parentId", response.getReturnValue());
     
                if (component.find("fileId").get("v.files") != null) 
                    // if user has attached any file with case 
                  // then call uploadHepler method
                {
                    alert('there is a file');
                      helper.uploadHelper(component, event); 
                }
                else // else show success message
                {
                    //hide spinner
                  helper.hideSpinner(component); 
                  //showing toast event on success
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    title : 'Success',
                    message: 'Record Created Successfully.',
                    duration:' 1000',
                    key: 'info_alt',
                    type: 'success',
                    mode: 'pester'
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
              //  $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
              component.set("v.ShowModule", false); 
                }
            }
           
            else if (state === "ERROR")
            {
            var errors = response.getError();
            alert('error is '+errors[0].message);
              //hide spinner
                  helper.hideSpinner(component); 
             }
           
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
           
   }
    })
```

> helper

```
({
   

 MAX_FILE_SIZE: 4500000, //Max file size 4.5 MB 
    CHUNK_SIZE: 750000,      //Chunk Max size 750Kb 
    checkFileLimit: 0,

 // this method checks if selected file size greater then MAX_FILE_SIZE
uploadHelper: function(component, event)
{
    var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
    // get the first file using array index[0]  
    for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.length; i++)
    {
        
        var file = fileInput[i];
        var self = this;
     
        if (file.size > self.MAX_FILE_SIZE) // check if selected file size greater then MAX_FILE_SIZE
        {
            var sizeInMB = (file.size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);// convert file size from bytes intoMB
             //hide spinner
            this.hideSpinner(component); 
            alert('Alert : File size cannot exceed 4.5MB' +  ' Selected file i.e. '+file.name+ ' size is: ' + sizeInMB +'MB');
            return;
        }
self.uploadFile(component, file);
    }
    
},

//this method creates a file reader object and  base64 formate 
uploadFile:function(component, file) 
{
        var self = this;
        var objFileReader = new FileReader(); 
        objFileReader.onload = $A.getCallback(function() 
         {
            var fileContents = objFileReader.result;
            var base64 = 'base64,';
            var dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
            fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
            self.uploadProcess(component, file, fileContents);
             
        });
    
        objFileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
},


// this method calculates file's chunk size
uploadProcess: function(component, file, fileContents) 
{
    var self = this;
    // set a default size or startpostiton as 0 
    var startPosition = 0;
    // calculate the end size or endPostion using Math.min() function which is return the min. value   
    var endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
    // start with the initial chunk, and set the attachId(last parameter)is null in begin

    this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, '');
},

// this method uploads file in chunks
uploadInChunk: function(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, attachId)
{
    debugger;
   
    var getchunk = fileContents.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
    var pId= component.get("v.parentId");
    var action = component.get("c.saveChunk");

    action.setParams({
        parentId: pId,
        fileName: file.name,
        base64Data: encodeURIComponent(getchunk),
        contentType: file.type,
        fileId: attachId
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
    {
        // store the response (Attachment Id  ) 
        attachId = response.getReturnValue();
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") 
        {
            // update the start position with end postion
            startPosition = endPosition;
            endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
            // check if the start postion is still less then end postion 
            // then call again 'uploadInChunk' method , 
            // else  display success toast msg and hide the loading spinner
            if (startPosition < endPosition) 
            {
                this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition,attachId);
            } 
            else 
            {  // check if all files have uploaded?
                var fileInput = component.find("fileId").get("v.files");
                 alert(this.checkFileLimit);
                this.checkFileLimit++;
                alert('AFTER'+this.checkFileLimit);
             if ( this.checkFileLimit == fileInput.length)
                {alert('equal');
              //hide spinner
                   this.hideSpinner(component);  
                  //showing toast event on success
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    title : 'Success',
                    message: 'Record Created Successfully.',
                    duration:' 1000',
                    key: 'info_alt',
                    type: 'success',
                    mode: 'pester'
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
              component.set("v.ShowModule", false); 
                }
            
            }
              
        } 
        
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE")
        {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
        } 
        
        else if (state === "ERROR")
            {
            var errors = response.getError();
            alert("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
             }
    });
    
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

   // this method shows spinner
showSpinner: function (component, event, helper)
{
    var spinner = component.find("mySpinner");
    $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
},

// this method hides spinner
hideSpinner: function (component, event, helper) 
{
    alert('hiding ');
    var spinner = component.find("mySpinner");
    $A.util.addClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
    },
})
```

Comment: Not sure of the use case but the 4.5 MB limit is likely to counter the heap size error. The lightning file upload component support multiple files OOTB (10 files max/ 2GB each). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation